# Drupal 8 create field programmatically

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-fields, drupal-field-api

I created a custom module for Drupal 8 that allows the users to choose a Content type in order to add some fields programmatically.
How I can create some fields (text type in this case) and attach they to a Content type with a custom module?

Some help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [Field API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.module/group/field/8) for Drupal 8

It has several functions implemented and [hook_entity_bundle_field_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_bundle_field_info/8) might be what you need, here is an example of textfield from the docs of that hook

```
function hook_entity_bundle_field_info(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle, array $base_field_definitions) {
  // Add a property only to nodes of the 'article' bundle.
  if ($entity_type->id() == 'node' && $bundle == 'article') {
    $fields = array();
    $fields['mymodule_text_more'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('More text'))
      ->setComputed(TRUE)
      ->setClass('\Drupal\mymodule\EntityComputedMoreText');
    return $fields;
  }
}
```

You might also need Field Storage, checkout [hook_entity_field_storage_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_field_storage_info/8)

Answer (score 3):

You need to create FieldType, FieldWidget and FieldFormatter(If necessary), there are good examples in Core/Field/Plugin/Field.

There is a good example here https://www.drupal.org/node/2620964

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module to create fields programmatically for any entity type and multiple bundles at once from custom YAML or JSON files:

https://drupal.org/project/field_create

The simplest approach for your module is to add your fields in the hook_field_create_definitions(). Simply create this function:

```php
function mymodule_field_create_definitions_alter(&$definitions) {}
```